# Zend Framework form Invalidating the form

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-form

I have created a form with zend form. 
I process the data in one action and then redirect to the another action.

So in case of an error I redirect to the last form, if there was no error I redirect the user to another url.

So when isValid() fails I use the getMessages() (the getErrorMessages doesn't return anything) to get the messages, serialize it, place it in a session property and then redirect to the form page. My problem is now setting those error msg's in the form to let the user know there was a problem.

I have tried this

```
$form->setErrors(unserialize($this->_session->form_error_msgs));
```

But this doesn't do anything. What do I have to do to display the error msgs next to the fields??

Comment: You can set form as invalid using `$form->markAsError()`.

Comment: @Marcin: setErrors does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should add the error to the field, for example

```
 $form->fieldname->addError('error message');
```

your code might not be working because you haven´t configured the form decorators...

Comment: I had to loop through the msgs and set each element's error msg. Thanks :)

Comment: just one more thing... did you try with setErrorMessages($messages)?